# Docker nginx reverse proxy on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a couple of applications, which runs in Docker containers (all on the same VM).
In front of them, I have an nginx container as a reverse proxy.
Now I want to migrate that to Kubernetes.

When I start them by docker-composer locally it works like expected.
On Kubernetes not.

#### nginx.conf

```
http {
        server {
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://app0:80;
                }

                location /app1/ {
                        proxy_pass http://app1:80;
                        rewrite ^/app1(.*)$ $1 break;
                }

                location /app2/ {
                        proxy_pass http://app2:80;
                        rewrite ^/app2(.*)$ $1 break;
                }
        }
}
```

#### edit: nginx.conf is not used on kubernetes. I have to use ingress-controller for that:

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app0
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app0
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: app0
        image: appscontainerregistry1.azurecr.io/app0:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: nginx
---
#the other apps
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: apps-url.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app0
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
```

I get the response on / (app0). Unfortunately, the subroutes are not working. What I´m doing wrong?

#### EDIT

I figured out. Ich missed installing the ingress controller. Like on this page (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) described, the ingress doesn't work if no controller is installed. 
I used ingress-nginx as a controller (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) because it was the best-described install guide which I was able to find and I didn´t want to use HELM.
I have one more question. How I can change my ingress that subdomains are working. 
For example, k8url.com/app1/subroute shows me every time the start page of my app1. 
And if I use a domain name proxying, it rewrites every time the domain name by the IP.

Comment: How does your `nginx.conf` get into the container?  (Is there a ConfigMap you haven't shown?  It'd have matching mount options in the Deployment spec.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for the answer. No idk ConfigMap. From my knowledge I added the conf on volumes in docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't know anything about your Docker Compose setup.  [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) in the Kubernetes documentation is an important read, it's the standard way to push in not-especially-sensitive configuration files like this.

Comment: all right. If I get you right, I don`t need the nginx.conf inside my docker-compose. The job on kubernetes is taken over by ConfigMap?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer so it might be helpful for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have created deployment successfully but with that service should be there. nginx ngress on kubernetes manage traffic based on the service.

so flow goes like

```
nginx-ingress > service > deployment pod.
```

you are missing to create the service for both applications and add the proper route based on that in kubernetes ingress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I get you right I need to configure my ingress-controller (nginx). I would do that in deployment.yaml with ConfigMap. Then I can skip mounting my nginx.conf in docker-composer. Am I on the right way?

Comment: yes you are on right way you have to deploy the nginx ingress controller and service.

Comment: follow this guide it wil help a lot : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Comment: I will. Thank you. Only one question for better understanding. is an ingress controller replacing the load balancer? Or is a loadbalancer still necessary for multiple node and forward to nginx ingress controller?

Comment: In the case of cloud providers, the Ingress is typically paired with load balancers. For example, the nginx ingress controller provides https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml for generic cloud providers to create a load balancer and a public endpoint that flows through your ingress.

Comment: @NicoSchuck as Andy Shinn provided the answer if the answer work for you can mark it as answer or upvote and update the status of the question as how it's work. Thanks a lot please let me know if any further question is there.

Comment: @AndyShinn thankyou for writing the answer you are right absolutely.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I changed my Question. I tried to set up with load balancer AND ingress. Is that correct?

Comment: @HarshManvar thank you for the fast answer. The LB points to ingress. Unfortunately, it´s not working. My Questions shows my current deployment.yaml. Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: @NicoSchuck in ingress rule you have mention the `backend:
          serviceName: app0
          servicePort: 80` but actually that service you have created or not ?

Comment: sorry, i recognized that I got the response from cache. / works with app0. But /app1 and /app2 shows error 404 not found from nginx.

Comment: did you created service name with app1 and app2 ? can you please share app1 and app2 yaml file if created.

Comment: I thought I created the services in deployment.yaml. Do I have to do further steps then to deploy images from my registry?

Comment: @NicoSchuck if you registry is private you have to add secret value if you image stored in public registry simple add the registry name and image in in yaml file at image section.

Comment: It´s a private repository. In my deployment file actually, the container is described like that: -name: app1 image: xxxxxrregistry1.azurecr.io/app1:latest. I passed to metadata labels: app: app1 which I used to point from ingress. Is something missing?

Comment: secret to fetch image from private repository.

Comment: @NicoSchuck please follow this guide and use `imagepullsecret :` https://thorsten-hans.com/how-to-use-private-azure-container-registry-with-kubernetes

Comment: I followed all these steps. I´m able to point from load balancer to all my apps. That is working. But it doesn't work with ingress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196129/discussion-between-nico-schuck-and-harsh-manvar).

Answer (score 1):

Add this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
```

Because you didnot route for `Service` Load balancer to `targetPort` to `80`

Comment: Is my ingress listen by default on port 80 or do I also have to point out that in my deployment.yaml?

Comment: I actually meant my LB is passing the request to my ingress. Do my ingress listen on port 80? because I didn´t describet that anywhere. Is that necessary because I believe my ingress is not reachable

Comment: please try to build it. then let me know

Comment: When I list my services (kubectl get svc) LB is listening to Port 80 and kubernetes to 443. Is that the issue? I expected that kubernetes is listening to port 80 and 443.

Comment: are you access the app ?

Comment: not via nginx. only if I use app1 (for example) on LB selector